# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

Why am I getting this error it will not occurred when I sync the gradle but when I am running the project I am getting this error .

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zzf.class

I don't know which dependency cause this error, My dependencies are .

```
dependencies {
compile project(':RNAdMob')
compile project(':react-native-maps')
compile project(':react-native-fcm')
compile project(':react-native-device-info')
compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
compile project(':react-native-calendar-events')
compile project(':react-native-device-token')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

compile (project(':react-native-fcm')){
    exclude group: "com.google.firebase"
}
compile(project(':react-native-maps')){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
}
compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1")
        {
            force = true;
        }
compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1")
        {
            force = true;
        }
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1') {
    force = true;
}
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1') {
    force = true;
}
compile (project(':react-native-device-info')){
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
}
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'){
    force = true;
}
```

}

Comment: Try to `exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"` from ':react-native-fcm' also.

Comment: not work for me @EvgeniiKanivets

Comment: Try to exclude it from everywhere one by one)

Comment: I had similar issues some time ago. Please look at my comment here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/247#issuecomment-315715926
Perhaps that can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @EvgeniiKanivets issue is solved

Comment: So what was the dependency which you excluded from?

Comment: I have add exclude group for all dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an issue usually caused by internal dependency of some of your dependency. So you need to exclude conflicted dependency from your dependency. But in most cases you as developer don't know which library you need to exclude from.

So just try adding `exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"` to all the libraries one by one and try compile. When project is compiled, you have found the needed library to exclude from.